# .net 4.5.1 Identity 2.0 share authentication between applications

Tags: identity, shared

I'm in the process of adding Identity 2.0 to our site redesign.  It's running fine as an application under the site root.  But the root can't see the authtication, re: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

I've tried quite a few options (matching machinekeys, etc) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am of view that for single sign on there is a bug in asp.net mvc5.1  templates available. I got the following workaround , For single sign on to work using machine key, One need to add two MVC project with web APi option checked . Then hosted the projects on iis and try single sign on by using the authorize attribute on WEBAPi functions. It is working with me . But i am not able to attain the same behavior with only WEB API based project selection. I am of view that there are bugs in the project selection and they should be address .

If you have other alternate solution using the OWIN based implementation do share .